# Declaring CustomViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have noticed in some of my older apps that in situations where I have added a custom View Controller I have not changed the View Controller class in the application delegate. For example, below I have created a CustomViewController class but have declared viewController as UIViewController.

```
@interface ApplicationAppDelegate: NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    UIViewController *viewController;
}
```

My question is, both work, but for correctness should I be writing this as follows:

```
@class CustomViewController;
@interface ApplicationAppDelegate: NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    CustomViewController *viewController;
}
```

gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, you should retrofit your existing member type definitions to be as specific as possible.**

In the header file, you should always **forward declare** your instance objects.

This saves you from actually importing the class header, thereby saving a little overhead.

**Forward declare as much as you can in header files, then `#import` in your implementation files.**

Here's an example:

**Header file:**

```
@class CustomViewController;
@interface ApplicationAppDelegate: NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    CustomViewController *viewController;
}
```

---

**Implementation file:**

```
#import "CustomViewController.h";

@implementation ApplicationAppDelegate

...

@end
```

Comment: Thank you, I think you just answered my next question too which I just posted about where to #inport. Much appreciated.

Comment: Can I just ask, in my first example above putting "UIViewController" is not correct, it should be "CustomViewController" ?

Comment: @fuzzygoat Yes. If the class is called `CustomViewController`, it should not be declared as its supertype.